# Handling XSD files in PHP?

Tags: php, xsd

I have a bunch of xsd files. I need to generate html forms based on those schemes. Xsds are very precise, they contain all required data (minOccurs, maxOccurs etc.). I don't believe there is any tool which would do that for me, so I imagine I need to somehow analyze the xsd file node by node.

And here is my question - is there any library in PHP for xsd handling? I need something, that would help me select nodes, read their names and types etc. Something like SimpleXML, but for xsds.

Comment: You happen to have an WSDL file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand you correctly (XSDs to create HTML forms?), but since XSD files are also just XML files you can use SimpleXML just as well here. Just pointing out the obvious i guess though.

Comment: Yes, user will fill out the form and then xml matching xsd filled with data from forms will be created. I didn't know if SimpleXML wouldn't require a file to have xml header or something... Thanks for your answer, I'll try with SimpleXML.